# DataFrame.from_dict generating columns and rows Pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this following code

```
df_output ={'transport':[transport],'model':[model],fuel':[fuel],'engine':[engine],'color':[color],'year':[year],'value':[value],'
number':[number],'manufacturer': [manufacturer],}
```

I pass `df_output` to be able to manipulate in `DataFrame.from_dict`

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=df_output, orient='index', columns=['transport', 'Model', 'Fuel', 'Engine', 'Color', 'Year', 'Value', 'Number','Manufacturer'])
```

i'm following the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) documentation

he tells me to use `orient = 'index'` so that I can create columns manually, then I pass the columns `columns=['transport', 'Model', 'Fuel', 'Engine', 'Color', 'Year', 'Value', 'Number','Manufacturer']`

when i will execute my code it generates me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Suporte\Desktop\Captura TJ\autonomation\Discovery.py", line 192, in <module>
    Scrape(user_tj, password_tj, pesquisa_unica)
  File "C:\Users\Suporte\Desktop\Captura TJ\autonomation\Discovery.py", line 54, in __init__
    self.single_search_csv()
  File "C:\Users\Suporte\Desktop\Captura TJ\autonomation\Discovery.py", line 182, in single_search_csv
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=df_output, orient='index', columns=['transport', 'Model', 'Fuel', 'Engine', 'Color', 'Year', 'Value', 'Number','Manufacturer'])
  File "C:\Users\Suporte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1190, in from_dict
    return cls(data, index=index, columns=columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\Suporte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 450, in __init__
    arrays, columns = to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\Suporte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 464, in to_arrays
    return _list_to_arrays(data, columns, coerce_float=coerce_float, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\Suporte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 503, in _list_to_arrays
    raise ValueError(e) from e
ValueError: 9 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns
```

after everything goes well i will generate a csv

`df.to_csv('file.csv', sep = ';', encoding = 'iso-8859-1', mode='a', index=False`)

who can help me thank you :)

Comment: `df.output` is failing to create multiple columns. Perhaps you could remove the `[brackets]` around the arrays you are passing to build a DataFrame from a dictionary.

Comment: I did what you suggested but it returns this error  ValueError: Shape of passed values is (9, 1), indices imply (9, 9)

in this part of the code
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=df_output, orient='index', columns=['transport', 'Model', 'Fuel', 'Engine', 'Color', 'Year', 'Value', 'Number','Manufacturer'])

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that it didn't work. My last guess is to do the same, but don't include the columns in the DataFrame constructor. On the next lines, write `df = df.T`, then `df.columns = ['transport', 'Model', ...]`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Your dictionary is fine, but when you pass it to the from_dict function and specify `orient="index"`, the dictionary keys are used as indices. This in turn means that your number of *columns* is the length of the lists used as dictionary values, which in this case seems to be one. It doesn't make much sense to me why you'd be passing the exact same names to columns as you already have in your index either, to be honest.

Comment: I researched a lot, I found a solution

Comment: #columns = list(df_output.keys())
   values = list(df_output.values())
   arr_len = len(values)
   df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(values, dtype=object).reshape(1, arr_len), columns=['transport', 'Model', 'Fuel', 'Engine', 'Color', 'Year', 'Value', 'Number','Manufacturer'])

Comment: the problem is if i put this inside a loop will be repeating column names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create *df_output*, drop square brackets surrounding each value.

I assume that *transport*, *model* and so on are lists.
The way you initially wrote, you unnecessarily create another set of lists,
each containg only one element (a list).

So change the instruction to:

```
df_output = {'transport': transport, 'model': model, ...}
```